# Can't use DB (trying to set active active mySQL database)

Tags: php, mysql

```
  // Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname, $db);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}
```

Error: Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/content/41/10663841/html/storelocator/phpsqlsearch_genxml.php on line 21
Can\'t use db :

Comment: is your mysql-connection working?

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere, wherever you're doing `mysql_connect`. Your other problem is that you're using mysql_* functions. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: If I get a penny for everytime I write don't use mysql_* I would be a millionaire by now..

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you've to connect to MySQL first:

```
// connect to mysql
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('cannot connect, error: ' . mysql_error());
}

// select db "xyz"
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('xyz', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('cannot select DB, error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Notice: For your future codes I recommend using PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Plus you shouldn't be using mysql_ functions as they have been deprecated. Use mysqli instead